# File renaming Linux

Tags: linux, rename

I have tried to rename several files on my Linux system.  I used`rename 's/foo/bar/g' *`  All the files that I wish to change are in the current directory.
It does not change the name of the files but I think it should.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `rename foo bar *` or just read the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html).

Comment: do you have enough permissions to rename the files?

Comment: Have a look at [rename files in directory](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98070/rename-files-in-directory)

Comment: Erwin Yes I have permission to change the files.

Comment: hasufell   The foo is just a string within the various names,

Comment: JGreenwell  yes I looked at the <rename files in directory> and notice a similar code segment which I believe is perl.  I thought s/ / /g was Bash.

Comment: hasufell Yes your code worked.  I am trying to learn about how s/ / /g works and why it didn't for me.

Comment: yes, rename is a perl5 function that can be linked toinstead of the built-in rename: to learn how the regex substr works in [perl 5 check out perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) or [in Perl 6](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Perl6-Rules-0.03/Rules.pm#Evaluated_substitutions).

Comment: JGreenwell   Thank you.  I will check out your referenced articles.

Answer (score 17):

An easy way would to do:

```
mv file2rename newname
```

Comment: thanks for short but the most useful answer.

Comment: short and  efficient, cool

Answer (score 3):

**You have mentioned that you want to rename multiple files at once using `rename` expression**. Technically you can't use only `*` sign for change file names. `*` means all files with same name. We know same file types doesn't exist with same name but you can rename some selected part from file. For an example

> admin@home:~/works$ `ls test*.c`
>   `test_car.c     test_van.c     test_dog.c`

- you can rename some part of these files not full name. because there cannot be exist same file name with same extention

> admin@home:~/works$ `rename 's/test/practice/' *.c`

- After executing this command every `test` replace with `practice`.

> admin@home:~/works$ `ls practice*.c`
>   `practice_car.c     practice_van.c     practice_dog.c`

Answer (score 3):

Rename a file mv

```
 mv old_name new_name
```

The use of the mv command changes the name of the file from `old_name` to `new_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to rename file extentions in the current directory, for instance renaming all `.txt` files in `.csv`:

```
for file in $(ls .); do
    mv $file ${file/.txt/.csv}
done
```

This will not affect files that don't have the `.txt` extention and it will prompt an error (should be developed further depending on your needs).

Answer (score 0):

#### some posts points out the usage of  `for x in $(something); do..`

##### please - Don't (ever, under any circumstances) use that! (see below)

Say you have a file(and, other .txt files):

```
"my file with a very long file - name-.txt"
```

and you do
`for f in $(ls *.txt); do echo $f; done`
(or something like that) it will output

```
.
..
a.sh
docs
my
file
with
a
very
long
file
-
name-.txt
```

(or something similar)

### Instead, try the following:

---

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo -n "example usage: bash $0 .txt .csv <DIR>"
    echo -n "(renames all files(ending with .txt to .csv) in DIR"
    exit
fi

A="$1"      # OLD PREFIX (e.g .txt )
B="$2"      # NEW PREFIX (e.g .csv )
DIR="$3*$A" # DIR     (e.g ./   )

# for file f;
# in path  $DIR;
for f in $DIR; do
  ## do the following:
  # || here just means:
  #         only continue IFF(if and only if)
  #         the previous is-file-check's exit-status returns non-zero
  [ -e "$f" ] || continue
  
  # move file "$f" and rename it's ending $A with $B (e.g ".txt" to ".csv")
  # (still, in $DIR)
  mv "$f" "${f/$A/$B}"
done
```

---

```
###    $ tree docs/

#    docs/
#    ├── a.txt
#    ├── b.txt
#    ├── c.txt
#    └── d.txt
#
#    0 directories, 4 files
#


###   $ bash try3.sh .txt .csv docs/


#    $ tree docs/
#    docs/
#    ├── a.csv
#    ├── b.csv
#    ├── c.csv
#    └── d.csv
#
#    0 directories, 4 files
##
#-------------------#
```

## References:

- [Bash Pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)
- [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)
- [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- [Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

```
 MAN's: ($ man  "- the following")
- bash
- mv
- ls
```

##### Note: I do not mean to be offensive - so please don't take it as offense (I got the main command-idea from **meniluca** actually!

But since it was (for x in $(ls ..)) I decided to create a whole script, rather than just edit.

Comment: If this can be improved, please feel free to point it out!